# How to use less mixins in meteor with @import and not get multiple definitions

Tags: meteor, less

in my current meteor app I have split the less declarations in one file per Controller (iron-router). I have a common file - where I have defined some mixins - which is imported in each less file. My problem is that the classes are imported multiple times in each route.

The file structure is:

mixins.import.less (new names, reference http://docs.meteor.com/#less)

```
.grid-container {
    // something
}
```

postList.less

```
@import (once) url('/client/views/mixins.import.less');
```

postDetail.less

```
@import (once) url('/client/views/mixins.import.less');
```

Then in the Chrome inspector I found duplicated everything I have written in mixins.import.less. Is it possible to avoid this double import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the mixin code at least once in your compiled css (perhaps not, some just want them as mixins, not classes in the css code), then make sure you set it to bring in the "mixins.import.less" file all by itself. Then for all your dependent files using it, do this:

"postList.less", "postDetail.less", etc.

```
@import (reference) url('/client/views/mixins.import.less');
```

[The `(reference)` option has been available since LESS 1.5](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference), and will only bring in the code for reference purposes to be used in the LESS file, but will not itself output any css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your solution is's working for the less declarations, but if I want to define some #ids or .classes in the imported files it is not working.

Comment: @Hamal000 That's why I noted that if you want some "mixin code at least once in your compiled css ... then make sure you set it to bring in the 'mixins.import.less' file all by itself." The `(reference)` call will not compile anything to output CSS. So you need to either somewhere (in _one_ place) import without `(reference)` or you need to make a direct call to load/compile that file by itself to get it to output the code at least once as finished css.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working: one "real" include and many reference include in each file.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor bundles css and js/html resources all together as a single css and a single js file in production.

In development, they are individually served, but still at the same time, during initial page load (first ever request to server)

For less files, a css file is created for each (during development). Since you are importing, what Meteor basically does is create each corresponding css file that each contain the import individually.

And when they are served to the client all together (take a look at the head section of the generated html), you end up with that many copies of the imported style declarations.

Therefore, due to this bundling behaviour of Meteor, you can just keep one copy of your less mixins in a less file, and not import at all, since they are going to be served to the client in CSS form anyway.

Also, it is possible to trick Meteor into bypassing as described in the [unofficial meteor faq](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#importing-in-less-files-causes-errors-related-to-variables-not-found):

> ... you can change the extension of the less files to be imported from `.less` to `.lessimport` and then change your `@import file.less` to `@import file.lessimport`. This will prevent the less compiler from automatically trying to compile all your import files independently, yet still let you use them ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not working. It seems that each .less file needs its @import to recognize the mixins defined in another file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's still not working. I had already used the suggestion quoted in the "unofficial meteor faq" when I made the question. The only difference it's that meteor changed .lessimport for .import.less (http://docs.meteor.com/#less)